# Creating a fully customized NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, customization, nsalert

Is it possible to create a fully customized alert? I'm doing it with custom sheets now, but I'd like to have the feature that the sheet is blocking (like `-[NSAlert runModal]`).

I just want to change the background, really, and the text color, of course.

Comment: Technically, it's not called a sheet if it's running in an app-modal way.

Comment: An app-modal alert with custom background and text color sounds like it could be pretty nasty. Do you really *need* to do this? Have you read the [Mac Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html)?

Comment: It's not nasty at all, really. Alerts don't fit my needs, since I'm working with a full-screen app and I'm using `NSStatusWindowLevel`. I've read those guidelines a while ago, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warning about the recommended solution:**

This code causes wasteful and pointless overhead:

```
for (;;) {
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSRunContinuesResponse)
        break;
}
```

This code is copied straight from the Apple documentation page - but it's meant to show the developer *where meaningful code can be inserted for background execution* while the modal runs. That is, you should have some code between the break and the closing bracket. But there's no actual code shown in the example - and running it like this simply causes your application to poll the session repeatedly until it ends. It's like the two-year-old in the back seat of the car on a road trip asking, "Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we there yet?..."

If you just want straightforward modal execution, where your application presents a modal window and suspends processing of main / background windows until the modal ends, use this:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow: self.window];
```

...and then exit the modal session when the window closes by dropping this into your window controller subclass:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need a custom window with custom view drawing, however `NSAlert` does not allow you to change its window. So you will need to write your own window controller subclass like `NSAlert` ( though `NSAlert` is a subclass of `NSObject` ).

Answer (score 2):

I looked around a bit, and found this piece of code :

```
NSModalSession session = [NSApp beginModalSessionForWindow:sheetWindow];
for (;;) {
    if ([NSApp runModalSession:session] != NSRunContinuesResponse)
        break;
}
[NSApp endModalSession:session];
```

I call

```
[NSApp stopModal]
```

to end the session.
Now my code is way cleaner :)